# Can't PING or nslookup outside the LAN

Tags: ubuntu, networking, linux-networking, vmware-esxi

Ubuntu 18.04 cannot PING or nslookup outside the LAN.

When I do `nslookup www.google.com`it hangs for a while and returns `;; connection timed out; no servers could be reached`.  I cannot PING [www.google.com](http://www.google.com) but I can PING 10.100.10.1, my gateway. The server is using netplan. When I do a `netplan apply`, I don't get errors. Here is my netplan config file.

```
network:
  version: 2
  ethernets:
          ens160:
            dhcp4: no
            dhcp6: no
            addresses: [10.100.10.26/24]
            gateway4: 10.100.10.1
            nameservers:
               addresses: [8.8.8.8, 8.8.4.4]
```

Here is my resolv.conf:

```
nameserver 8.8.8.8
nameserver 8.8.4.4
```

I can't install apps because it cannot resolve DNS.

This is an image from a ESXi implementation. Other images in the network respond to all network requests except this Linux client.

Comment: Show not a configuration file but `ip addr` and `ip route` from the running system. Last should display a line similar to `default via 10.100.10.1 dev ens160`; try `ping 10.100.10.1` (or whatever your actual default route is) and see if *that* works.

Comment: And check if there is a firewall blocking your outbound requests.

Answer (score 0):

It was related to the firewall, there are two types of NAT that can be figured on the firewall: 1 to 1 with Nat, or 1 to many with NAT.

What worked was 1 to many with NAT.

Answer (score 0):

It's a little tricky. This issue could be either a routing issue or a firewall.

Check this:

1. Verify your  Internet and path using `traceroute` command, if `traceroute` shows the right path to Internet that mean you have a FW that is blocking the DNS service.

   `traceroute -n 8.8.8.8`

If the last hub in the `traceroute` output command  is a router/moden/fw it means that your traffic is being forwarded on the right path, so a firewall device is likely blocking the DNS service.